# Are Meteor template events lost if the template is relocated within the DOM?

Tags: meteor

I have two lists that appear adjacent to each other on my page. List items can be dragged from one list into the other, and vice-versa (using jquery.sortable). The list item is a template, within which is a button. The click event for the button is defined using the Template.my-button.events method.

When the page is rendered, if I click this button in a list item, the events fire ok. If, however, I drag this list item into the adjacent list, the events no longer fire.

Does anyone know why this is and/or can suggest a way to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible *jquery.sortable* messes with Meteor events tracker. Maybe not the most elegant way but a possible work-around would be to add an eventListener through classic JS in your `Template.page.onRendered()`. 
Something like:

```
Template.yourPage.onRendered(function() {
    document.getElementById("yourButtonId").addEventListener("click", function() {
       #your code
    });
})
```